# Curried class constructor with more than two levels of currying

Tags: scala, class, constructor, currying, case-class

I have been using currying with scala for literally years, but recently had reason to write a class  constructor that is sort of a builder, where I don't want c and d to be optionals, so I don't want the class to be instantiated until they are available.

If I define my class thusly:  `MyClass(a: Int, b: Int)(c: String)(d: Long)`

This compiles fine, but when I try to instantiate it like so:

val myConstructor = `MyClass(a, b)(_)(_)` //this is the only notation that works

the compiler thinks `myConstructor` is a `(String, Long) => MyClass` instead of a `String => Long => MyClass`

and I can't call myConstructor(someString) to get a Long => MyClass

Surely this is possible, but not finding how to instantiate it in a way the compiler likes.

Is this event possible with constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always define a function yourself `def f(X:String)(y:Long) = My class(a,b)(X)(y)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was that I had not defined `MyClass` as a case class.  It works as expected for case classes.